# Why A = B = C not the same as A = B AND B = C AND C = A in MySQL Case When Statement?

Tags: mysql, case, operators

Here is a table Numbers:

```
+--+--+--+
|A |B |C |
+--+--+--+
|1 |1 |1 |
|1 |2 |1 |
|2 |2 |2 |
|3 |2 |1 |
|3 |3 |3 |
+--+--+--+
```

Now executing the query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (A = B = C) THEN "Equal" ELSE "Not Equal" END AS Equality FROM Numbers;
```

gives the output as:

```
+----------+
|Equality  |
+----------+
|Equal     |
|Not Equal |
|Not Equal |
|Not Equal |
|Not Equal |
+----------+
```

But executing the query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (A = B AND B = C AND C = A) THEN "Equal" ELSE "Not Equal" END AS Equality FROM Numbers;
```

gives the output as:

```
+----------+
|Equality  |
+----------+
|Equal     |
|Not Equal |
|Equal     |
|Not Equal |
|Equal     |
+----------+
```

Why isn't `A = B = C` treated the same as `A = B AND B = C AND C = A` here?

Is this a MySQL thing or an issue with Case When Statement, where applying two operators won't work properly?